# Java library to export database from any DBMS to any DBMS

Tags: java, sql, export, database

Is there a java library that be able to export databases from any DBMS (Mysql,SQLServer,Oracle,SQLite,...) to any DBMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats not easy.. but you could try using apache torque, it will convert your source schema into an intermediate XML. You can then use the XML to generate your schema in the target database. After which you can call on ant targets to export the data into XML from the source database. Then call another ant target to  populate the data from the data XML.

I have used this to migrate data from mysql to oracle express to db2. It worked fine for me. In fact it worked better that the oracle provided tools for migration.

Here's a link:

http://db.apache.org/torque/releases/torque-3.3/generator/tasks-reference.html